How to make the entire checkbox module clickable in Bootstrap 5
I'm trying from a long time to make the whole module clickable, not only the checkbox or the label.
If you search on stackoverflow about this you can find the question
How to Make Entire Custom Checkbox/Div Clickable -- Not Just the Label + Input
but it's not my case.
It's a custom checkbox and I want to use a normal one.
So at the end watch at my try with this code in the snippet (some JavaScript & JQuery)


var checkboxes = []; //There are multiple checkboxes so an array it's needed to simplify [pretend nothing happened ]
checkboxes[0] = document.body.querySelector('#HEYY');
checkboxes[0].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log('CLICKED@'+Date.now());
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ma_checkbox_module').on('click', function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.target.tagName == "DIV") {
        let checkbox = $(this).find('input');
            if (checkbox.prop('checked') == true) {
                checkbox.prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                checkbox.prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>


<center><!-- center tag it's deprecated, but who cares -->
<div class="user-select-none" style="background-color: #983229;">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block" style="background-color: #111111;">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="HEYY">
            <label class="form-check-label ms-3" for="HEYY" style="color: white;">HEYY</label>
        <!-- class .ms-3 is added specifically to create more space to simplify understanding of the example, but it's the same also if you remove it -->
        </div>
</div>
</center>



As you can see it works good, but the event it's not triggered in some cases (goes well by using the keyboard, it'the click that needs to be managed).
If you click on a specific point between the label and the checkbox, the checkbox changes state but the change event it's not triggered. Instead, clicking on the label or the checkbox triggers the event change.
How to make it work perfectly without changing the HTML code?

The issue arises because the change event on the checkbox is not triggered when the click event is handled on the surrounding div (.ma_checkbox_module). This is because the checkbox state is manually toggled in your jQuery event handler, bypassing the natural behavior that would trigger the change event.

@ Anoop LL
"The issue arises because the change event on the checkbox is not triggered when the click event is handled on the surrounding div (.ma_checkbox_module). This is because the checkbox state is manually toggled in your jQuery event handler, bypassing the natural behavior that would trigger the change event." Woah. Very nice explanation. But how to fix it? An example is needed.

There is a super simple way to do this: The stretched-link Bootstrap class.  Refer to this section in the documentation.  Skip until you read:

You can use .stretched-link on <label>s to make the whole list group item clickable.

As you can see, the example provided there check or unchecks the checkbox by clicking anywhere in the container list item, not just on the label or the checkbox.
How stretched-link Works
This works by inserting ::after and styling it like this:
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1;
content: "";

I'm not going to give an entire lesson on this technique, just know this:  This creates a transparent on-top layer that covers the most immediate parent that has absolute or relative positioning.
If you need help understanding, read about the topic @ MDN.

Ramirez Great answer. I didn't know about this class. I actually didn't read the topic completely. But unfortunately in my HTML case it messes up my final result. So it would probably be better to use JQuery/JavaScript to achieve the goal. Here's a link with a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/ty7L3er4/1/ .Try clicking all three checkboxes

I don't see the definition of the parent elements.  It seems that you did not make suitable parents.  This is why only the first checkbox works.

Your demo has another error:  All the ID's are the same for all checkboxes.  So every label refers to the first checkbox.  Add different ID's to the different checkboxes and it will work.

To make suitable parents in your demo:  Add the class position-relative to each div.form-check.  The ones with the almost-black color.

Yess. I was in error. As you can see the parents were correct. They were inserted. The mistake was in having inserted all the same ids (sorry, but as you could see I did it very quickly). With the changes you proposed and inserting the classes you wrote it works. In any case I would like to understand how to make the checkboxes work using JavaScript & JQuery. Anyway you deserved a +1 to your answer because it solves the problem. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/3awjn1tf/ to the code of what you proposed. The sun shines on you

@user27160653 you should accept the answer as well by clicking the ✔️.

@zer00ne yes, I should accept the answer as well by clicking the ✔️ (also because it's well, and that's not to say I won't do it!). But as you can read "I would like to understand how to make the checkboxes change event works using JavaScript/JQuery". So, if there's someone that knows ho to do it I would much prefer it, also for pure personal knowledge. Anyway, thanks for the proposal. U're welcome.

@user27160653 see my answer.

@zer00ne Look @ my dab
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUDM384agTA

As @Anoop LL suggests, the issue arises because clicking the surrounding div element manually toggles the checkbox state via JavaScript but doesn't trigger the change event that would normally occur when the checkbox itself is clicked. To resolve this, explicitly trigger the change event programmatically after toggling the checkbox.
The updated JavaScript code using JQuery could be:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ma_checkbox_module').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName === "DIV") {
            let checkbox = $(this).find('input');
            $(this).find('label').click();
        }
    });
});

Indeed:

click() ensures the change event is fired programmatically after manually toggling the checked property of the checkbox.
Toggle logic: checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked')) cleanly switches the checkbox's state without needing additional conditionals.

When you toggle the checkbox manually, you're responsible for also firing any associated events.
Now, clicking anywhere in the clickable module, including the gap between the label and the checkbox, will properly toggle the checkbox and trigger the change event.

@ Deleter your explaination it's good. But at at the end your code should work well and the console should write CLICKED! Here your response coded: https://jsfiddle.net/L14jth2b/
Change it and make it work to get a thumbs up on your answer

@user27160653 you got me! I tried your jsfiddle and made some adjustments. Now this version should be correct in every browser (using click rather than trigger("change")). Try it out! Thx

@ Deleter SO?!?! I got you, but where's the link of the jfiddle to try it? "Every browser" seems a bit too much to me. It's an adjustment that I would like to make the product more usable for the user. Let me try your "click rather than trigger("change")". I'm curious to see how it goes.

@user27160653  here you are https://jsfiddle.net/hubkqmf3/

MMMM NO. Sorry, I'M NOT HERE ! Change event it's triggered, but the checkbox has always the same state when you click between the label and the input. Too bad because it works for the trigger.

A final solution is to trigger click on label https://jsfiddle.net/m1z5tyxu/3/

YESSSSS! Mr. Violet Deleter. This solution works!...but you are a smart guy because you bypassed the problem with your code in the jsfiddle by not dealing with the checkbox input and simulating the click on the label. So you avoided dealing with the checkbox change event (which was what I was really interested in). You are very very smart

I was not aware that you had an extra requirement:  To trigger the checkbox's change event.  My bad because apparently it was in the question.
According to the official documentation @ MDN, the change event only fires on user interaction.  Programmatic changes on the checked property do not fire the event:

When a <input type="checkbox"> element is checked or unchecked (by clicking or using the keyboard);

The solution, then, is to dispatch it.
$(() => {
  $('.form-check').on('click', (e) => {
    const cb = e.currentTarget.querySelector('input');
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
    const event = new Event('change');
    cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
  // This sets event handlers that verify that the event is received.
  $('.form-check input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', (e) => {
    console.log('changed: %s', e.currentTarget.id);
  });
});

This of course is problematic by itsef:  When clicking on the label or the checkbox, the click event also triggers in the parent DIV, which triggers the artificial change event.  So one has to complicate the above solution to also handle the click event of the checkboxes to prevent it from bubbling up.
So I post this answer to satisfy your curiosity, but I do not recommend this path at all.
Using the stretched-link class as stated in the other answer (which should be the accepted answer here, in my opinion) is THE way to go.

The honest truth? You didn't use a JavaScript event listener to trigger the change which is what I wanted to know to document myself a bit (is JQuey). But your solution works. It will trigger the change. And I'm fed up. So I'll put solved to your previous answer which seems to me the most obvious and the most functional to do. Also because creating "artificial" events with const event = new Event('change'); cb.dispatchEvent(event); in my opinion is something that bomb disposal experts should . Using stretched-link. Thanks and congratulats. Your code: https://jsfiddle.net/ng328k4f/

"change" event is when certain form controls get data from the user and the user "unfocuses" on the form control.

Examples

<input type="text"> or <textarea> user types into it then  clicks elsewhere.
<input type="checkbox"> or <input type="radio"> user clicks it.



The "change" event can be triggered by a "click" event because a click involves the same requirements as a "change" event on checkboxes. There is an example in jQuery and in vanilla JavaScript  . Both of them listen for a "click" event on any .ma_checkbox_module and synthetically changes the checkbox inside of it and triggers a "click" event on it as well. There is an event handler (changeHandler()) that handles the "click" event triggered on it as well as "change" events triggered by the user. Details are commented in the examples.
jQuery


/*
  Initialize each checkbox "checked" default value
  to false.
*/
$(".form-check-input").each(function() {
  $(this).prop("checked", false);
});

/*
  If user clicks any ".ma_checkbox_module" function clickHandler will be 
  called.
*/
$(document).on("click", clickHandler);

/*
  If user clicks then unfocuses on a ".form-check-input" function 
  changeHandler will be called.
*/
$(document).on("change", changeHandler);

/**
 * This event handler will find the checkbox within the 
 * ".ma_checkbox_module" that the user clicked and toggle whether it's 
 * checkbox is un/checked.
 * Next, it will fire a "click" event on said checkbox which is
 * actually a "change" event on a checkbox or radio button.
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 * @return {boolean} - false which prevents bubbling
 */
function clickHandler(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is(".ma_checkbox_module")) {
    const $chx = $(event.target).find(".form-check-input");
    /*
      $chx jQuery object is dereferenced into a
      DOM object so that .toggleAttribute() method
      can be used.
    */
    $chx[0].toggleAttribute("checked");
    $chx.trigger("click");
    return false;
  }
}

/**
 * This event handler will be called when a "change" event happens on a 
 * ".form-check-input" (checkbox).
 * It will log: 
 *   - the type of event
 *   - checkbox position
 *   - whether it's un/checked, 
 *   - a timestamp
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 * @return {boolean} - false which prevents bubbling.
 */
function changeHandler(event) {
  const $chx = $(event.target);
  const idx = $(".form-check-input").index($chx);
  let status = $chx.prop("checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
  console.log(`
  "${event.type}" event was 
  triggered on Checkbox ${idx + 1}
  making it ${status} at 
  ${new Date().toLocaleString()}
  `);
  return false;
}
/* Avoid using the [style] attribute */
.user-select-none {
  background-color: #983229;
}

/* For demonstration purposes */
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

/* For demonstration purposes */
.as-console-row::after {
  display: none !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <style>
    /* 
      Custom CSS goes here inline or externally 
      as the last <link> 
    */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <!--
            Wrap <input> in <label> to avoid using
            #id and [for] attributes and still
            be valid.
          -->
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 1</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>-->
  <script>
    /* 
     Custom jQuery goes here inline or externally 
     as the last <script>
   */
  </script>
</body>

</html>



JavaScript


// Gather all ".form-check-input" into an array.
const allChx = [...document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input")];

/*
  Inialize all checkboxes to [checked] default
  value of false.
*/
allChx.forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.checked = false;
});

/*
  If user clicks a ".ma_checkbox_module", the 
  function clickHandler will be called.
*/
document.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

/*
  If the user clicks and unfocuses on a checkbox,
  or if the "change/click/input" event is triggered
  on a checkbox, the function changeHandler will be 
  called.
*/
document.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);

/**
 * If the user clicks a ".ma_checkbox_module",
 * this event handler will find the checkbox inside it,
 * toggle it's [checked] attribute, and trigger
 * a "click" event on said checkbox which triggers
 * a "change" event on it.
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 */
function clickHandler(event) {
  if (event.target.matches(".ma_checkbox_module")) {
    const chx = event.target.querySelector(".form-check-input");
    chx.toggleAttribute("checked");
    chx.click();
  }
}

/**
 * If the user clicks and unfocuses on a checkbox,
 * or if the "change/click/input" event is triggered
 * on a checkbox, this event handler will log:
 *   - type of event
 *   - checkbox's position
 *   - whether it's un/checked
 *   - a timestamp
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 */
function changeHandler(event) {
  const chx = event.target;
  if (chx.matches(".form-check-input")) {
    const idx = allChx.indexOf(chx);
    let status = chx.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked";
    console.log(`
    "${event.type}" event was 
    triggered on checkbox ${idx + 1}
    making it ${status} at 
    ${new Date().toLocaleString()}
    `);
  }
}
/* Avoid using the [style] attribute */
.user-select-none {
  background-color: #983229;
}

/* For demonstration purposes */
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

/* For demonstration purposes */
.as-console-row::after {
  display: none !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <style>
    /* 
      Custom CSS goes here inline or externally 
      as the last <link> 
    */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <!--
            Wrap <input> in <label> to avoid using
            #id and [for] attributes and still
            be valid.
          -->
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 1</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="user-select-none col">
        <div class="form-check ma_checkbox_module d-inline-block bg-dark">
          <label class="form-check-label bg-light pe-2">
        <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox">
        Checkbox 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>-->
  <script>
    /* 
      Custom JavaScript goes here inline or externally 
      as the last <script>
    */
  </script>
</body>

</html>




OMG @ zer00ne You wrote a peace treaty in your comments in the answer. But that's what I was looking for. Kudos for the answer. This is code written by a real programmer. And you also offered both solutions: JQuery and JavaScript (Vanilla is Good ). I don't understand why you initialize the checkboxes every time, but who cares. Anyway, the answer to do everything in a simple way goes to José Ramírez. But you will always be my God.

I used .toggleAttribute() .  <input type="checkbox" checked="false"> is interpreted slightly different than as a property const chx = document.querySelector("input") chx.setAttribute("checked", true) is also chx.checked = true but chx.toggleAttribute("checked") needs to have the [checked] attribute set explicitly first. I should've added that bit in comments but I was getting tired .  Dab .

@ zer00ne Understood. .toggleAttribute() must be set as checked false #COMMENTGOD. GoodNight. Tomorrow u will be revitalized! . Dab.  P.S. Very good answer. Very good work.
